# Does MySql DBMS change queries to use index before they execute it?

Tags: mysql, indexing

When I query, using '!=' or '<>' I know then the DBMS does not use indexes.

```
select * from test where test_id != 1234
```

So querying like bottom, you can have the same result using indexes.

```
select * from test where test_id < 1234 or test_id > 1234
```

But when I see the explain plan both uses range(range scan).
So I'm curious about, if I query using '!=' does MySql DBMS change the query like '> and <' to use the index.

Comment: The query selects most part of rows - in this case the index usage is not effective, and the table scan is preferred.

Comment: There are a lot of factors that will impact when an index is used.  You are not going to get answers to a contrived simple case that will help you in real situations.  If you have a real case you are concerned about, ask about that.

Comment: `test_id < 1234 and test_id > 1234` is always false!  What did you really mean?  Maybe `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Opps... its OR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!=` (aka `<>`) usually means "I want all rows except for one".  So having an index on that column is essentially useless; it is faster to scan the table, skipping over that one row.

```
WHERE test_id < 1234 OR test_id > 1234
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE test_id != 1234
```

But `OR` usually cannot use any index.